# Swift: Using Protocol inside another Target can´t find some properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I currently have a big problem inside my ios application.

Our Project structure looks like this:

- 1 SDK (3rd Party Library), written in **Objective-C**
- 1 "Common" framework, which contains the shared code (overall most code lives here & everything related to the SDK from above)
- different targets for different clients, which are just defining custom colors and custom images for our "Common" framework.

Inside the Common framework we added a new Protocol to wrap all of the SDK features, it looks somehow like that:

```swift
protocol SDKRepositoryProtocol {

var oneClassFromSDK : SDKClass123 { get set }
[...]
var otherTestProp: SDKCustomDate { get set } 

}
```

So `SDKClass123` and `SDKCustomDate` are private classes from the SDK.

Using the SDKRepository class works fine inside our "Common" Framework and most of our targets are built successfully with no errors at all.

**Now, here is the problem:**

If we now want to use the `SDKRepositoryProtocol` inside one of our targets, the IDE is supporting our usage and IntelliSense shows all of the protocols variables, but if we want to compile our **Swift** file we get an error like:

`Value of type 'SDKRepositoryProtocol' has no member 'oneClassFromSDK'`.

Note:

- this only happens on the 'Release' Build Configuration & not in DEBUG

And what even is more mysterious, if we try to access `repoProtocol.otherTestProp` its working in both Build Configurations.

---

So, next we tried to use the same Protocol inside our TargetAppDelegate for the same target (which is still written in Obj-C).
And there is no issue using the property `repoProtocol.oneClassFromSDK`

So is there any other problem if we just create a new extension for TargetAppDelegate (for using Swift) ? Do we need to define sth. more ?

---

So, for me it seems like:

a) the compiler for release builds is causing problems and removes properties, which he thinks are not used ('oneClassFromSDK')

b) the overall SDK is not imported into the target, because `oneClassFromSDK` cant be used inside Swift, but `otherTestProp` compiles without problems

c) *hope you have some good ideas*

---

**summary**:

- we have a protocol inside the common framework
- inside AppDelegate (**ObjC**) of the target we have access to all properties (Debug & Release Builds)
- inside the Swift Extension from AppDelegate we have **no** access to some properties (not all), and only in the *Release Build*

Things we tried:

- some general stuff: Clean Build / Clean Derived Folder / Not working on another PC
- we already tried to find differences inside the debug / release configuration

  - we did not find any
  - we also tried to just "brute-force" the configuration from another target (where we can use the protocol)
- we checked if the file is included twice, so there are two mismatching protocols, but inside our project file its only once

  - we also tried to toggle the target membership, because this helped in the past to reset issues inside the project configuration file

---

**Edit:**

So, we could minify our problem to basically one file:

```
class MyCustomServiceInTarget: NSObject {
    let shello: SDKClass123
    let repo: SDKRepositoryProtocol

    init(repoProtocol: SDKRepositoryProtocol) {
        self.repo = repoProtocol

        var x = repoProtocol.oneClassFromSDK // Will produce an error 
    }
```

So, inside this Service we get the error like above. The Service was used inside the Targets AppDelegate, so it initially showed up there, too.

**Now, imagine:**
If we comment out the line `let shello: SDKClass123` and try to use the `repo.shell` property again, it is working !!! :O :O

Can anybody explain this ??

Comment: Just to make sure: everything in your common framework is declared `public` or `open`, right?

Comment: @Yonat Yes, that´s right.

Comment: But if `SDKClass123` and `SDKCustomDate` are private classes, how do you expect to use them outside the framework?

Comment: the private framework is also imported in the main application.
We can do let myClass = SDKClass123() just fine, but when we access the property of the protocol it doesnt work.